# How to get value from td tag and use it in foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to retrieve value carried in td tag that show value from database.Then i need to insert them in different database.From model i retrieved two values which are seatNumber and seatLabel and show them in checkboxex that carries seatNumber value.

my model for get seatValue

```
public function getSeats(){
      $query = $this->db->get('seat');
      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      return $query->result();
      }  
 }
```

my view for displaying seatNumber and seatLabel

```
<tbody>
            <?php if(count ($seats)):?>

        <?php foreach ($seats as $seat):?>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" value=<?php echo $seat->seatNumber;?>></td>
            <td id="seatLabel" name="seat_label"><?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php else:?>
        <td>No Records Founds!</td>
        <?php endif;?>          
        </tbody>
```

My controller

```
public function message(){
    if ($this->input->post('submit') == 'Set Schedule') {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('busNumber','Bus Number', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('seat_id[]','Seats', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('bookingDate','Date of Journey', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('reportingTime','Reporting Time', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('departureTime','Departure Time', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $seat_ids = $this->input->post("seat_id[]");
            $seat_label = $this->input->post("seat_label");
            $busNumber = $this->input->post("busNumber");
            $bookingDate = $this->input->post("bookingDate");
            $reportingTime = $this->input->post("reportingTime");
            $departureTime = $this->input->post("departureTime");
            $this->load->model('Queries');
     $insert = $this->Queries->saveMessage($seat_ids, $seat_label, $busNumber, $bookingDate, $reportingTime, $departureTime);
            if($insert) {
                echo "Success";
            }
            else {
                echo "error";
            }
        } else { 
         echo validation_errors();
        }
    }
```

My model for inserting date to new database

```
public function saveMessage($seat_ids, $seat_label, $busNumber, $bookingDate, $reportingTime, $departureTime){

    foreach($seat_ids as $seat_id)
    {
        $record = array(
        'seatNumber' => $seat_id, 
        'seatLabel'  => $seat_label
        'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
        'reportingTime' => $reportingTime,
        'departureTime' => $departureTime, 
        'busNumber' => $busNumber,
        'seatUse' => 'Enabled',
        'seatStatus' => 'Available',);
        $this->db->insert('schedule', $record);
    }
return true;
```

}

[image]

THE PROBLEM COMES IN DATABASE THERE IN NO SEATLABEL VALUE

[image]

ERROR

[image]

Comment: Your td name is `name="seat_Label` and in post you are getting with capital L `$this->input->post("seat_label");` please change this,,is this have some effect ? and in model your are using this parameter ` $seat_label` and getting its value with   `$seatLabel`

Comment: Not setting any input type for seat label so u will never get its value by post

Comment: @Coeng this error indicated that seat label value is not setting.

Comment: my dear i am saying u have not set any input for seat label in your form so how u will get u seat label data in your  post

Comment: in your form do  like this : `<td><input type="text" name="seat_label" value="<?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?>"></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way like this. if you change this

```
<td id="seatLabel" name="seat_label"><?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?></td>
```

to

```
<td><input type="text" name="seat_label" value="<?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?>"></td>
```

but if you don't want to show the text box, then create hidden field also.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="seat_label" value="<?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?>">
<td><?php echo $seat->seatLabel;?></td>
```